# Как создать таблицу в visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Подскажите, как создать в visual studio таблицу наподобие stringgrid в  delphi. Начинаю только изучать С#, раньше только в delphi программировал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблица создается с помощью класса [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx). Обзор использования (частично устаревший) можно почитать здесь: [DataGridView. Новый контрол в составе Framework 2.0](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/DataGridView20.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Если для создания интерфейса используете WPF, то таблицу можно реализовать с помощью [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx).